# Java: create a middleman class between multiple threads accessing a non synchronized class?

Tags: java, concurrency

So taking cues from this question [Multithreaded access to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302769/multithreaded-access-to-file)

My scenario is I have a spreadsheet component in which multiple threads will access and write to each workbook.  The component itself is not thread safe and so am I correct in thinking that while a thread is writing to it, other thread needs to be blocked until the first one is finished writing? How would I going about to achieve this when I am dealing with a non thread safe class? put the writing method in a synchronized block?

another concern this raises is that what if one thread is busy writing long rows of data to it's respective workbook, the other thread would have to stop dead in it's tracks until the first one is finished, and this is not desirable.

instead, I imagine a scenario where each thread runs without blocking each other but the data being written to the spreadsheet is done by another middleman class which will buffer and flush the data onto spreadsheet componenet without causing multiple threads to "wait" until their writing process is complete.

Basically each thread does two things on it's own. 1) performs some long running processing of data from each respective source, 2) the writing of processed data to the spreadsheet. I am seeking a concurrent solution where 1) faces no "waiting" due to 2).

Answer (score 1):

The best solution really depends on the types of operations that you're performing on the spreadsheet. For example, if one thread needs to read the value written by another thread, then it's probably necessary to lock either the whole spreadsheet or at least specific rows at a time. Since the spreadsheet itself isn't thread safe, you're correct that you'll need to do your own synchronization.

If it's important to serialize all access (which hurts performance, as it gets rid of parallelism), consider using a thread-safe queue, where each thread adds an object to the queue that represents the operation it wants to perform. Then you can have a worker thread pull items off of the queue (again, in a thread-safe manner, since the queue is thread-safe) and perform the operation.

There may be room here to parallelize the queue workers, since they can communicate with each other, and do some row-based locking amongst themselves. For example, if the first operation is to read rows 1-4 and write to row 5, and the 2nd operation is to read fro rows 6-10 and write to row 11, then these should be able to execute in parallel. But be careful here, since it may depend on the underlying structure of the spreadsheet, which you say isn't thread safe. Reads are probably fine to perform in parallel nonetheless.

While non-trivial, synchronizing access to a queue is the basic readers-writers problem, and while you have to make sure to avoid starvation as well as deadlocks, it's a lot easier to think about than random-access to a spreadsheet.

That said, the best solution would be to use a thread-safe spreadsheet, or only use one thread to ever access it. Why not use a database-backed spreadsheet and then have multiple threads reading/writing the database at once?